# TableViewCell Accessory Selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

An accessory, Detail Disclosure, was configured for a cell in a `TableViewController` that segued into another `TableViewController` which worked fine.

Then it was changed on the `Storyboard` to `Disclosure Indicator` and it no longer works. There are no errors or anything to indicate why this happened. How can it be fixed?

Comment: changing it back works, changing it to 'Detail' works as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to work:

> - **DisclosureIndicator**
>
> The cell has an accessory control shaped like a
>   chevron. This control indicates that tapping the cell triggers a push
>   action. The control does not track touches.

From documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html